# what will happen if i delete FreeDOS partition?

Tags: partitioning

[Gparted image of my HDD's partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2BKb.png)

The first partition has the boot flag and has FreeDOS inside.
The second partition seems empty, as I dont find anything there, but I'm curious what the lba stands for.
The extended partition belongs to ubuntu 14.04

What will happen if i delete partition 1 right away from gparted? Will I still be able to boot into ubuntu? Because it's the only boot-flagged partition, I assume grub is installed there and it will be erased as well.

Comment: @EdiD after i deleted the first partition (together with grub) will the ubuntu partition be lost aswell? if not, can i install windows in a new partition i make (NTFS) and reinstall grub into it? I just want to know if this will work.

Comment: @EdiD, no it isn't correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can delete the partition.  The boot flag only has meaning to Microsoft boot loaders.  GRUB is installed in the MBR and will continue to work as long as it can find your Ubuntu partition.